# CanCanCan not stopping posts being edited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I'm making a rails project, and I'm trying to implement [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan). I installed the gem and the ran the commands. I then added this to `ability.rb`:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:

      user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
      if user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
      else
        can :update, Post do |post|
          post.user == user
        end
        can :destroy, Post do |post|
          post.user == user
        end
        can :create, Post
        can :read, :all
      end

  end
end
```

However, now in my project, if I sign into a different user, I can still edit other users posts.

Any help with what I'm missing will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was solved by adding `load_and_authorize_resource` to my posts_controller

Comment: glad to hear it...you should then mark the question as answered for the benefit of other SO users

Answer (score 0):

According to CanCanCan documentation,

> The block is only evaluated when an actual instance object is present.
>   It is not evaluated when checking permissions on the class (such as in
>   the index action). This means any conditions which are not dependent
>   on the object attributes should be moved outside of the block.
>
> don't do this
>
> ```
> can :update, Project do |project|
>   user.admin? # this won't always get called
> end
> ```
>
> do this
>
> ```
> can :update, Project if user.admin?
> ```

So instead of

```
can :update, Post do |post|
  post.user == user
end
can :destroy, Post do |post|
  post.user == user
end
```

Change that do

```
can :update, Post if post.user == user
can :destroy, Post if post.user == user
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion and it didn't seem to stop users from editing other users posts

Answer (score 0):

---

Try something like `can :manage, Post, :user_id => user.id`

As you can see at https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion and it didn't seem to stop users from editing other users posts

Answer (score 0):

I have it set up the same way as nersoh, and that method works for me.  Have you tried authorizing the Posts resource in the controller?  For example,

```
class PostsController < ActionController::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource
end
```